# Как записать данные в Excel?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Как записать числа от 1 до 10 в Excel?

В моем случае он записывает только последнюю цифру. Как я понял, он каждый раз перезаписывает данные. Как избежать этого?

```
i = 0
while i < 10:
    print (i)
    i=i+1
    df['new'] = [i]
```

Comment: Какое отношение имеет код в вопросе к Excel?

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 5):

При работе с Pandas мыслить нужно векторами и матрицами, а не скалярами и циклами. Векторные решения будут работать на порядки быстрее и код будет короче, аккуратнее и понятнее:

```
import numpy as np

df['new'] = np.arange(1, 11)
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы в одну и тоже место. вам надо использовать метод `append`

```
i = 0
df['new'] = [] 
while i < 10:
    print (i)
    i=i+1
    df['new'].append(i)
```

место цикла `while` лучше использовать цикл `for`

```
df['new'] = []
for i in range(10):
    df['new'].append(i)
```

либо [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
df['new'] = [i for i in range(10)]
```

либо так:

```
df['new'] = list(range(10))
```